# Plivo SMS Response in php

Tags: php, plivo

I am trying to use Plivo sms using php SDK. I am able to send message correctly:

How can i get the **Response** as in the following link so that i can store it in my Database:

https://api-reference.plivo.com/latest/php/resources/message/the-message-object

Example Response:

```
{
  "error_code": "200",
  "from_number": "18552828641",
  "message_direction": "outbound",
  "message_state": "failed",
  "message_time": "2016-08-17 21:26:44+05:30",
  "message_type": "sms",
  "message_uuid": "85ce8068-6fab-4f0a-9dc7-d6c852cdde91",
  "resource_uri": "/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Message/85ce8068-6fab-4f0a-9dc7-d6c852cdde91/",
  "to_number": "19352326448",
  "total_amount": "0.00000",
  "total_rate": "0.00350",
  "units": 1
}
```

For example, I need to know message_state, total_rate etc.

`var_dump($message);` gives following results

```
object(Plivo\Resources\Message\MessageCreateResponse)#32 (2) 
    { ["messageUuid":protected]=> 
    array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "39006dc4-fe7a-11e7-b939-06755d68f0ca" } ["_message":"Plivo\Resources\ResponseUpdate":private]=> string(17) "message(s) queued" }
```

I tried using `$message->message_state` but keep getting errors.

Unfortunately Plivo documentation and support is very poor.

Comment: What error are you getting?  
can you post output of `var_dump($message);`?

Comment: @Ataur Rahman I have updated my original post with var_dump results

Comment: I am not familiar with their api, but seems like `$message->getMessage();` will give you message_state.  I hope someone experienced will help you to get details.

Comment: Poor documentation and lack of support from Plivo. Lack of examples for their new API version. Twilio API is far better.

Answer (score 0):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

The response that you're looking for is from a different API which can be found here - [Retrieve a Message](https://api-reference.plivo.com/latest/php/resources/message/retrieve-a-message). This API returns details of a particular message which includes the Message State.

$client->messages->get($id) is the corresponding function in the [new PHP SDK](https://developers.plivo.com/server-side-sdks/php-sdk/).

Let me know if this doesn't resolve your issues.

Comment: This is the issue with Plivo. We ask something and the support (mostly from some overseas call center with shoddy support) tells a part or totally unrelated answer.  In my question i asked for "message_state, total_rate" etc.

Comment: Anyway we opted for Amazon SNS SMS, with better rates. Plivo it seems are also using Amazon SNS for their services. We set it up within 10 minutes.

Comment: $response = $client->messages->get($id); returns the response that you're looking for and $response->message_state gives you individual parameters (total_rate etc). GET response to the Message API returns the Message Object.
Plivo does not use Amazon SNS. We have direct connects with Tier 1 carriers globally and runs on our own infrastructure. You can read more about this here https://www.plivo.com/network/.